# POST form loaded with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am having problems making PHP check when the submit button from a form is clicked,  but that form is loaded through jQuery. So, I have the *if(isset($_POST["submit_content"]))*, and when that is done, to echo "will be sent" using the variable $content but it does nothing.

Here is my index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>INDEX</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<?php
session_start();
$content = "";
if(isset($_SESSION["logged"]))
{
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ntech") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
    $get = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE ses_id='$_SESSION[logged]'");
    $got = mysqli_fetch_array($get);
    $header_account = "Signed in as ".$got[1]." | <a href='?&logout=true'>Logout</a><br/>";
    $access = $got[6];
    if($access >= 2) //moderator - can submit & edit
    {
        $content = "<p id='content'></p><script>$('document').ready(function(){
            $('#content').load('mod_view.html');
            });</script>";
            if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
            {
                if(isset($_POST["mod_view_radio"]))
                {
                    $val = $_POST["mod_view_radio"];
                    if($val == "radio_send")
                    {
                        $content = "<p id='content'></p><script>$('document').ready(function(){
                                $('#content').load('send_content.html');
                            });
                            </script>";
                        if(isset($_POST["submit_content"]))
                        {
                            $content = "will be sent";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $content = "<p id='content'></p><script>$('document').ready(function(){
                                    $('#content').load('see_content.php');
                            });</script>";
                        if(isset($_POST["text"]))
                            echo "LOLED";
                    }
                }
                else
                    echo "nothing set<br/>";
            }
            //else echo "not submitted<br/>";
    }
}
else
    $header_account = "<a href='login.php'>Login</a> | <a href='register.php'>Register</a>";
?>
<body>
<?php echo $header_account.$content; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the send_content.html, which is loaded with jQ:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p {margin:0;}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" id="send_content" method="post">
    <input type="number" placeholder="year" name="year" id="year">
    <input type="number" min="1" max="31" placeholder="day" name="day" id="day">
    <select placeholder="month" id="month" name="month">
        <option>January</option>
        <option>February</option>
        <option>March</option>
        <option>April</option>
        <option>May</option>
        <option>June</option>
        <option>July</option>
        <option>August</option>
        <option>September</option>
        <option>Octomber</option>
        <option>November</option>
        <option>December</option>
    </select><br/>
    <h6>*NOTE: Years below 0 will be considered as years B.C.!</h6><br/>
    <textarea placeholder="Description" style="max-width:350px" name="description" id="description"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit_content" id="submit_content">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? Please, help!

Comment: I can tell you for sure that your call to `header("Refresh: 1; url='index.php'");` will fail in its current placement in your script. By the time that statement would execute, you've already started outputing HTML. It should throw an error or warning (don't remember which) at this point. Something to the effect of _"Headers cannot be modified. Output already sent."_...

Comment: Does adding `value="Submit"` to your submit button help?  `isset` should return true even if the value is empty, but doesn't hurt to try.

Comment: @War10ck I have no trouble whatsoever with the logout() function, tried it on other sites too. Of course, I could use a jQ to refresh or something like that, but that function works for me like a charm.

Comment: @user2908353 That's surprising. It shouldn't work.

Comment: @Kyle just tried it, it does not work

Comment: If you uncomment your `echo 'not submitted'` line and submit the form, is that as far as you get?  Add a few echo statements in your file to see exactly where the script gets to.

Comment: @Kyle it gets all the way to the *if($val == "radio_send")*, changes the $content so it will load the send_content.html page and echoes it on page.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your question, then.  In your post, you made it sound like nothing was printing out.  What are you expecting to happen vs what is actually happening?

Comment: @Kyle Well, when the Submit button -from the send_content.html- is pressed, it should echo "will be sent", but it doesn't. Instead, it gets be back, to the content of the mod_view.html which contains 2 Radios: See content ; and Send content.

Answer (score 0):

from what i can tell $content will always be

```
"<p id='content'></p><script>$('document').ready(function(){
      $('#content').load('send_content.html');
  });
</script>";
```

whether `if($val == "radio_send")` evaluates to `true` or `false`.

And since `echo "LOLED"` only gets called when `if(isset($_POST["text"]))` evaluates to `true`, it might just be that `if($val == "radio_send")` returns `false` and the script goes down the `else` branch.